# Python multiprocessing Lock.acquire() keeps blocking even if Lock is released and even returns True

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have the following piece of code.

```python
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def f(l,a):
    print("Acquiring lock in f")
    l.acquire()
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        a.put([2,3])
        a.get()
        print("In f a is: ", a.get())
    finally:
        l.release()
        print("Just released lock in f")

def g(l,a):
    print("Acquiring lock in g")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(l.acquire())
    try:
        print("In g a is: ",a.get())
    finally:
        print("In finally")
        l.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = mp.RLock()
    data = mp.Queue()
    data.put([1])
    p1 = mp.Process(target=f, args=(l,data))
    p2 = mp.Process(target=g, args=(l,data))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p2.join()
    p1.join()
    l.acquire()
```

The output reveals that the Lock.acquire() in g() does not allow further execution even if it returns True when the lock is released somewhere else. Any idea of what is wrong here? I have used Lock instead of RLock, not printing the result of the acquire() returned value, not using try and finally block but will always get the same result.

```
$ python first.py 
Acquiring lock in f
Acquiring lock in g
In f a is:  [2, 3]
Just released lock in finally
True
```

Comment: could it be that `l.acquire()` actually worked and `a.get()` is blocking?

Comment: That was definitely the problem! Thank you!